# I have an ampersand in my string which does get read in a teradata like/like any statement

Tags: sql, teradata

```
sel count(*) from tablename  where
lnk_name like  ('Specialty Online Platforms & Marketplaces|E-junkie|%')
```

The ampersand in the above like statement does not get read and hence the number of rows returned is zero.

Kindly help me getting this right.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by *The ampersand in the above like statement does not get read*? If this is not returning the number of rows starting with *'Specialty Online Platforms & Marketplaces|E-junkie|'*  you might have a client side problem, check the submitted SQL in the QueryLog.

Comment: I mentioned '&' symbol present in my string as ampersand

Comment: I know that `&` is an ampersand, but what is *does not get read*? Doesn't match existing data? DOes it work when you use an underscore wildcard instead?

Comment: A quick and dirty workaround to whichever problem is messing up the ampersand is to just replace it with a dot.  It is likely you won't get any expected matches, but should work with the rows you are looking for.

Comment: @MikeWodarczyk - Not a dot (`.`) but an underscore (`_`)

Comment: P.s. `like` is an operator, you don't need the brackets.

Comment: I suspect `LIKE ALL ('%Specialty Online Platforms%', '%Marketplaces|E-junkie|%'`) is what you are after.

Comment: `select case when   'Specialty Online Platforms & Marketplaces|E-junkie|something'
    like  'Specialty Online Platforms & Marketplaces|E-junkie|%'
  then 'yes' else 'no' end
;`  works fine.  Data in table is/is not Unicode?, Your client/ODBC session too?